# Println output much slower in windows 10 CMD versus GoLand Console

Tags: go

I have written a very short and simple Go program. All it does is output 0-999999. I am very confused because the output is MUCH faster in the Console for GoLand IDE as opposed to the Windows 10 CMD. I have also tested with PowerShell and Git Bash. Both are also A LOT slower than GoLand IDE.

I'll post the code below as well as time taken from the code ran in CMD and GoLand IDE Console. Thank you.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    start := time.Now()

    for i := 0; i < 1000000; i++ {
        fmt.Println(i)
    }

    elapsed := time.Since(start)
    fmt.Println("Time took:", elapsed)
}
```

GoLand IDE Console: Time took: 2.1853708s

Windows 10 CMD: Time took: 37.3894414s

Comment: That is probably because printing in Goland is faster than real terminals.

Comment: I think if you write to files, the difference will not appear.

Comment: I understand that the printing is faster in the GoLand Terminal. I was more or less trying to get the reason behind why this is the case. There will be no difference in writing to files, correct. Because when doing so, there will no longer be any comparison. GoLand doesn't have anything to do with writing to a file so I don't see how that would be an accurate representation of finding an alternative "difference".

Comment: I don't have a GoLand IDE so I am just making (educated) guess: GoLand actually redirect the output stream to a file and reads the file - it does not do realtime output streaming.